# deleting data from webservice not showing anything? XAMARIN

Tags: c#, web-services, xamarin, asp.net-web-api

I have been trying to delete a data using "DeleteAsync" and it doesn't show anything neither an error, when i hit delete buttom nothing happens.
although things seems fine to me, but you guys help where i missed?

**this is the code**

```
private async void Delete(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        private const string weburl = "http://localhost:59850/api/Donate_Table";
        var uri = new Uri(string.Format(weburl, txtID.Text));
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var result = await client.DeleteAsync(uri);
        if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Successfully", "your data have been Deleted", "OK");
        }
    }
```

Comment: a) try using the IP instead of localhost.  b) verify that you can load that url from the device's webbrowser c) are you sure your service responds to the DELETE verb?  d) if result returns anything besides a 200 you just ignore it - you should test for that

Comment: Use Postman to check whether the service works with Delete, as Jason mentioned, then integrate it into xamarin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your web API url appears to be wrong as the `weburl` is set using

```
private const string weburl = "http://localhost:59850/api/Donate_Table";
var uri = new Uri(string.Format(weburl, txtID.Text));
```

Note the missing placeholder in the `weburl` yet it is being used in a `string.Format(weburl, txtID.Text`

From that it would appear that the `weburl` was probably meant to be

```
private const string weburl = "http://localhost:59850/api/Donate_Table/{0}";
```

so that the `id` of the resource to be deleted will be part of the URL being called.

Also it is usually suggested that one avoid repeatedly creating instances of `HttpClient`

```
private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
private const string webUrlTempplate = "http://localhost:59850/api/Donate_Table/{0}";
private async void Delete(object sender, EventArgs e) {        
    var uri = new Uri(string.Format(webUrlTempplate, txtID.Text));        
    var result = await client.DeleteAsync(uri);
    if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
        await DisplayAlert("Successfully", "your data have been Deleted", "OK");
    } else {
        //should have some action for failed requests.
    }
}
```